# Proper cat breed's wife for our Persian cat

Tags: cats, behavior, multi-pet-families, introducing-pets

We have a 3 year old, male, Persian cat:

[image]

and because he is alone, I wanted to bring another cat, so do you think I must bring female Persian cat for him? What should be the optimal age of his wife, and if I bring another cat breed like DSH's cat, how do you think these two will do together?

Our cat is not very active and of course one of his hobbies is to run away in the yard, which he has just learned, so we let him go out less and when someone is in the yard, he goes into the yard.

So do you think other female cat breeds, like female Persian cat or female DSH cat, are comfortable with these conditions?

Thanks.

Comment: "Wife" is an odd term here -- are you meaning the same thing as companion? Is your cat not neutered?

Comment: Yes he is neutered, and I am searching for some companion for him, and thinking it would be better a female cat.